# Avoid suggests, recommends and upgrades during `apt-get install`?

Tags: apt

How do I avoid installing the recommended packages and suggested packages along with upgrading the packages when I `apt-get install` a particular package?

Comment: Use `apt-mark hold package-that-apt-should-leave-alone`. *hold
           hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically
           installed, upgraded or removed.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggested packages are not installed by default, to install suggested packages you need to explicitly use `--install-suggests` option (or set `APT::Install-Suggests yes` apt configuration parameter).

Now, to avoid installing Recommended packages, either use `--no-install-recommends` option with `apt-get` or set `APT::Install-Recommends "0"` in anyplace referred by `Dir::Etc::Main` (typically `/etc/apt/apt.conf`) or `Dir::Etc::Parts` (typically `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

Similarly, to avoid upgrading packages, either use `--no-upgrade` option with `apt-get` or set `APT::Get::Upgrade "0"` in anyplace referred by `Dir::Etc::Main` or `Dir::Etc::Parts`.

---

In a nutshell, with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-upgrade <package_name>
```

Comment: Is one `-` missing at the beginning of `-no-install-recommends`?

Answer (score 2):

In other to install a package without the *recommended packages* is to run the install command with the `--no-install-recommends` option like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends package_name
```

Don't upgrade packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-upgrade pkg_name
```

Don't install new packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade pkg_name
```

> --no-upgrade:
>
> Do not upgrade packages; when used in conjunction with install, no-upgrade will prevent packages on the
>              command line from being upgraded if they are already installed. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Upgrade.
>
> --only-upgrade:
>
> Do not install new packages; when used in conjunction with install, only-upgrade will install upgrades for
>              already installed packages only and ignore requests to install new packages. Configuration Item:
>              APT::Get::Only-Upgrade.

So to achieve what your asking:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-upgrade pkg_name
```

Source: `man apt-get`

Comment: Thanks ! but how about suggested ones and packages that will be upgraded? How do I avoid those?